# Why can't I view the stored played list from my app?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am trying to pick up the songs within a custom playlist in the music app, but when I return the results I don't get the title of the songs.

```
    let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery()
    var query = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery()
    let predicateByGenre = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "myPlaylist", forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName)
    print(mediaItems)
    let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mediaItems.items!)
    print(mediaCollection) //prints <MPMediaItemCollection: 0x15da4ad0>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enumerate the items using `-[MPMediaItemCollection items]` of the collection and query their title using `-[MPMediaItem title]`.